# 'overlay2' is not supported over nfs" storage-driver=overlay2

Tags: docker

when I am start docker(version 18.09.6) using:

```
service docker start
```

the log output:

```
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[21199]: time="2019-09-14T23:47:24.058391699+08:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420166a80, READY" module=grpc
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[21199]: time="2019-09-14T23:47:24.065016392+08:00" level=error msg="'overlay2' is not supported over nfs" storage-driver=overlay2
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[21199]: Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: backing file system is unsupported for this graph driver
```

this is my deamon.json config:

```
{
    "data-root": "/data/docker/lib/docker",
    "storage-driver": "overlay2",
    "storage-opts": [
      "overlay2.override_kernel_check=true",
      "overlay2.size=1G"
    ]
}
```

what is problem with my docker? this is the full log output:

```
Sep 14 23:47:23 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Sep 14 23:47:23 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[21199]: time="2019-09-14T23:47:23+08:00" level=warning msg="The \"-g / --graph\" flag is deprecated. Please use \"--data-root\" instead"
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[21199]: time="2019-09-14T23:47:24.054488483+08:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[21199]: time="2019-09-14T23:47:24.054528530+08:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[21199]: time="2019-09-14T23:47:24.054680027+08:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]" module=grpc
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[21199]: time="2019-09-14T23:47:24.054720022+08:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[21199]: time="2019-09-14T23:47:24.054796786+08:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420166680, CONNECTING" module=grpc
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[21199]: time="2019-09-14T23:47:24.055020881+08:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420166680, READY" module=grpc
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[21199]: time="2019-09-14T23:47:24.058007723+08:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[21199]: time="2019-09-14T23:47:24.058029632+08:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[21199]: time="2019-09-14T23:47:24.058172958+08:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]" module=grpc
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[21199]: time="2019-09-14T23:47:24.058204756+08:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[21199]: time="2019-09-14T23:47:24.058254343+08:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420166a80, CONNECTING" module=grpc
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[21199]: time="2019-09-14T23:47:24.058391699+08:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420166a80, READY" module=grpc
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[21199]: time="2019-09-14T23:47:24.065016392+08:00" level=error msg="'overlay2' is not supported over nfs" storage-driver=overlay2
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[21199]: Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: backing file system is unsupported for this graph driver
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Sep 14 23:47:24 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Sep 14 23:47:26 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 14 23:47:26 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Sep 14 23:47:26 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for docker.service
Sep 14 23:47:26 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Sep 14 23:47:26 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Sep 14 23:47:26 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

Comment: Is `/data` an NFS mount?  The error message suggests the Docker root directory can't be over NFS.

Comment: Yes,I just found this point.@DavidMaze

Answer (score 0):

The point is my host(total 5) mount a share nfs disk.Change the path should solve the problem.

```
[root@iZuf63refzweg1dh94t9Z containers]# df -T /data
Filesystem                                      Type      1K-blocks      Used      Available Use% Mounted on
3761b-lrf18.cn-shanghai.nas.aliyuncs.com:/ nfs4 10995116277760 233244672 10994883033088   1% /data
```

change the daemon.json root path to local:

```
{
    "data-root": "/var/lib/docker",
    "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```